# Is there a way for the Bash shell to throw a run time error when an integer variable is misused (by attempting to store a string into that variable)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, debugging

Bash 4.3 shell on Linux Mint:

I realize the Bash shell is type-less, or has a very weak form of typing.  But can the Bash shell be invoked (e.g. with some option) such that the shell will throw a run time error when a declared integer variable is misused (e.g. by attempting to store a string into that integer variable)?

Example code:

````
declare -i age

age=23
echo "$age"   # result is 23
age="hello"
echo "$age"   # result is not the string hello - wish I could get an error message here!```
````

Comment: `hello=37 ; age=hello ; echo "$age"`

Comment: @user4556274 I am not trying to solve a bug in the code. I am trying to figure out if there is a way for the bash shell to throw some kind of error message when trying to interpret the last line of code.

Comment: @tale852150 the point is that `age=hello` is a valid statement even if `age` is of type integer: `hello` is interpreted as an arithmetic expression.

Comment: Ditto. `age=hello` is not "attempting to store a string into that integer variable". It's like `age=$((hello))` because this is the behavior turned on by `declare -i age`.

Comment: All these comments are correct: when bash sees `age=hello`, and age has the integer attribute, the right-hand side is an arithmetic expression. In an arithmetic expression, "bare" words are treated as shell variables, and shell variables that are null or unset are treated as zero.

Comment: The above statement is documented in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic

Comment: @StephenKitt Understood that it is valid. What I want to know is if there is a facility within Bash to let one know something like "Hey, you know you just put a string into a   variable that is declared as an integer?".  Other languages have such tools (for example, lint programs) which will flag possible issues that, while valid, can maybe be an issue.  I don't think Bash has this capability but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: @tale852150 the point is that `age=hello` *isn’t* putting a string into an integer-declared variable (and yes, the ambiguity is often annoying).

Comment: @StephenKitt Good point.  Would ```age="hello"``` be a better way to express my question?

Comment: @tale852150 possibly, but Bash interprets it in the same way... I think glenn jackman’s answer is all you can do here.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all your feedback.

Comment: `age="hello"` is exactly the same as `age=hello` -- bash will perform [Quote Removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal) before actually executing the assignment.

Comment: You can set a `DEBUG` trap and turn on `extdebug`, which would allow you to control which commands could be let through. Or you could switch to a shell like ksh93, which allows to declare setters and getters for variables (via its "Discipline Functions" feature). Eg. `foo.set(){ [[ ${.sh.value} = bar ]] || echo foo can only be set to bar; }; foo=baz`.

Comment: @mozvy thx.  You should put those comment as an answer and upvote the OP question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to throw an error is:

```bsh
set -u
# or
set -o nounset
```

Then:

```bsh
$ set -u
$ declare -i age
$ age=hello
bash: hello: unbound variable
```

However it won't always "work" the way you expect if it's *not* an unbound variable:

```bsh
$ hello=world
$ age=hello
bash: world: unbound variable

$ hello=42
$ age=hello
$ echo $age
42

$ hello=""
$ age=hello
$ echo $age
0
```

---

I've come to think there's very little value in `declare -i`. It lets you do arithmetic without arithmetic syntax, and I think that just adds a layer of confusion.

Comment: The OP is probably thinking about age="hello". Too bad the code was not fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I suspected there was no way to get Bash to issue an error or warning.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Fixed code.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani what do you mean "fixed"? Do you mean my answer, or the OP's question, or bash?

Comment: The OP code had a problem. `age="hello"` is the actual line (as the comment in the code states). Some comments brought attention to that, but the OP changed it after your answer. You answer is ok based on the original code, but I believe that is no longer the case.

Comment: If you see my latest comment on the question, there is zero difference between using the quotes and omitting them.

Comment: @glennjackman there is no way you could get a "unbound variable" message if you were using quotes. (FWIW I think the OP code was, unwittingly, misleading).

Comment: Really? Do this and tell me what you see: `set -u; declare -i age; unset hello; age="hello"`

Comment: You are right. It's right in the documentation, first strip the quotes, then evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have a runtime type checking exception in `bash`. The reason is that when you use [`declare -i`](https://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_10_01.html) you are only telling `bash` to do arithmetic expansion `$((...))` on any value assigned to the variable. It's more about the value than it is about the variable.

Just as

```
$ echo  $(("hello"))
0
$ echo  $(("hello" + 2))
2
```

when you assign "hello"

```
$declare -i myvar
$ myvar="hello"
$ echo $myvar
0
```

You can check yourself if the value to be assigned is an actual number. There [many ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash).

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I suspected there was no way to get Bash to issue an error or warning.